# Indefinite Integration - Fallacy - modulus in log in answer creates problems

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have been taught that the indefinite integration of 
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx = \log |f(x)|$$

But this question was asked in AIEEE 2004:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\cos x - \sin x}$$

We may easily get that the answer is 
$$\text{My answer:  }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log \left| \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right| +c$$

But the options are

$$(i)\ \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log \left| \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right| +c$$
and
$$(ii)\ \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log \left| \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)\right| +c$$

and both are correct according to me. Am I missing something? What have I done wrong?

I am even not able to derive the second option from the first but you may differentiate both my answer and the last option to get the answer. You wont get the answer by differentiating the first option but theoretically the first option is the same as my answer.

**EDIT**
*More explanation*

The differentiation of $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left|\tan \frac{x}{2}\right|\right) = \frac{1}{\sin x}$$

So option (i)'s differentiation is $$\frac{1}{\sin x - \cos x}$$

While my answer's and option (ii)'s differentiation is $$\frac{1}{\cos x - \sin x}$$

Comment: $\tan x$ is an odd function.

Comment: Even though $\tan x$ is an odd function its surrounded by modulus operator so it makes no difference

Comment: That's right...

Comment: Is it wrong to add the source of question on math.se? (It was earlier edited out)

Comment: Hey everbody, if you cant answer please vote up so that other people can see this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer and option 1 both are equal and incorrect while only option 2 is correct. I think you have mistaken and assumed that  log|tanx|= log|cotx|  which is incorrect and the correct one is log|tanx|= -log|cotx|.

Comment: Try differentiating my answer. You will get correct result.

Comment: And yes differentiate without performing any manipulations. Manipulate only at the end

Answer (score 1):

The option 2 is correct ; option 1 and your answer is same and further, you have done **wrong** differentiation for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the two options, the arguments to tan inside the log differ by $\pi/2$; that makes them rather different. I like the first one (assuming your earlier work is right -- seems to be on a quick reading), because by $\tan(-u) = -\tan(u)$, you can make it equal to your answer.

Comment: You may differentiate both my answer and the last option to get the answer. You wont get the answer by differntiating the first option but theoretically the first option is the same as my answer.

Comment: Your answer and option 'i' are equal as functions, because $\tan$ is odd. Perhaps your differentiation work is incorrect, because equal functions have equal derivatives. Why don't you show us your work rather than explaining why we're wrong?

Comment: I have edited. Do you need more explanation?

Comment: I have edited more

Comment: Your answer has an absolute value in it; the differentiation that you offered does not. Do you think that the loss of an absolute value might explain a missing minus sign?

Comment: Maybe yes. But then I know only one rule and I dont know when not to use the rule. If you know more about it or a good resource can you link it please

Comment: *Calculus*, by Michael Spivak, the chapter called "techniques of integration" and its associated problems. Rather than give a bunch of rules, he carefully presents the theorems that justify the rules. The rule you cite, in computing the derivative above, for instance, has a constraint: it's only valid where $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ is positive; in applying it, you ignored that constraint (perhaps because you didn't know it was there!) and therefore ended up with an error.

Comment: In indefinite integration we cant know if its positive or negative

Comment: I believe you need to study carefully just what an indefinite integral *is*, including its domain of definition.